# How to improve Improve Page loading time, Request is fetching data from 9 mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am fetching data from 9 mysql tables having millions of records in it against a specific id or foreign key so page loading take 7 seconds to fetch data and rendering in browser,which technique i have to follow that page load time reduce.Half of tables consist essential data and other half non-essential but need to show user.

#### My Approach

Currently i'm fetching essential data on php request and other half is fetching on page load using ajax, but still taking 3 seconds to render.
each table has 8 column almost.Query is like below

**select * from table 1 where foreign_key_column = 200;**
same query for other tables.

Comment: Provide queries and table definitions; we're not psychic.

Comment: Use cache if records are static?

Comment: @Uueerdo against a table i have write query select * where foriegn key, i have also mentioned in question.